# Maximum Likelihood Estimate and Bayesian Estimation. $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ vs $f(x_1,...,x_n | \theta)$

Tags: probability, statistics

In part (a) of the question (in image below), $$f(x_1,...,x_n) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda \sum x_i}$$. Then in part (b) I am supposed to use the bayesian method. The way I understand it, I need to find $f(x_1,...,x_n | \color{red}{\theta})$ is $f(x_1,...,x_n) = f(x_1,...,x_n | \theta)$? Because it appears to be treated the same in the answer provided.

[image]

Answer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full answer to the only question asked in this post:

> The way I understand it, I need to find $f(x_1,...,x_n | \color{red}{\theta})$ is $f(x_1,...,x_n) = f(x_1,...,x_n | \theta)$?

Yes it is, with $\theta=\lambda$.